# Accessing value of a dictionary for use in table view

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary

I'm getting some data back from Firebase. The data comes back in a dictionary of key and value pairs. I access the values of the dictionary like this

```
  print(dateForPlanits.values)
```

and my output is this:

> [Jul 2, 2018, Jul 2, 2018, Jul 2, 2018, Jul 2, 2018]
>   [Jul 2, 2018, Jul 2, 2018, Jul 2, 2018]

When trying to display those values in a table view, as so:

```
cell.dateOfPlanitLbl.text = dateForPlanits.values[indexPath.row]
```

I get this error:

> 'Generic parameter 'Key' could not be inferred'

Any help or workaround would be appreciated. Seems like a small issue but I've been at it for far too long.

Edit:

dateForPlanits is declared as so

```
   var dateForPlanits = [String : Any]()
```

and it is populated on the previous VC, i am using a segue to pass over the downloaded FB data. I instantiated the data, Then i pass it over like this

```
   friendsUpdateSegue.dateForPlanits = feedObjectsArray[(friendsFeedTV.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!].keyForPostedPlanits
```

So keyForPostedPlanits is the actual dictionary. If i were to do

```
print(feedDetails.keyForPostedPlanits.values)
```

i get the same output as i do with the above print call

Comment: Show how `dateForPlanits` has been declared and populated.

Comment: @rmaddy updated the question now. thanks

Comment: First thing to realize is that a Dictionary is not a good basis for a table view's data model. Dictionaries have no order. You need an array. So start by reorganizing your data into an array.

Comment: @rmaddy I do that, however, the only way that i am able to append those values into a dictionary is by declaring the dictionary like this - var dates = [Any]() - which works, but when i try and use that data to populate the T.V cells like this -  cell.dateOfPlanitLbl.text = dates[indexPath.row] as! String - i get a crash

Comment: Can you show the class declaration that is saved in dictionary? It does not look like a simple string. But you need strings for your labels and compiler is complaining for that as the values in dictionary are not strings.

Comment: It is saved as [string:any]

Comment: Or I’m not exactly sure what you mean exactly @Kamran

Comment: `cell.dateOfPlanitLbl.text = Array(dateForPlanits.values[indexPath.row])`? But Dictionary aren't ordered, so there is no guarantee that `dateForPlanits.values` will always be in that order.